# 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. even though gcc is installed correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

im learning c++ and ive just set it up on vs code and as soon as i run it says 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
i went to cmd and checked the gcc version and it said gcc (GCC) 9.2.0 so im a bit lost on what the issue is can someone help

Comment: is g++ in your path? check https://www.google.com/search?q=vcod+g%2B%2B+not+recognized+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: So `gcc --version` works, but `g++ --version` doesn't? That is odd. Usually `g++.exe` is in the same directory as `gcc.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to PATH in your Window System Variables.

Answer (score 0):

Go to advance setting in your pc control panel->set path to your g++.exe path->save it
run command again